# How to print a list comprehension with strings and integers and add a symbol only to the strings?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a mixed list of integers and strings and I need to print '**' after strings only.

```
data = [4, 'Fred', 'London', 34, 78, '@#=£', 89, 'Ice cream', 'Hamilton', 12, 'tingle']
[print(data, end='**') for data in data if isinstance(data, str)]
```

This is the output:

`Fred**London**@#=£**Ice cream**Hamilton**tingle**`

Desired output:

`4, Fred**, London**, 34, 78, @#=£**, 89, Ice Cream**, Hamilton**, 12, tingle**`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` is now filtering the list `data`. Put it before the `for`. Also, use `str.join` to join the various strings with `,` :

```
data = [4, 'Fred', 'London', 34, 78, '@#=£', 89, 'Ice cream', 'Hamilton', 12, 'tingle']

print( ', '.join('{}**'.format(item) if isinstance(item, str) else str(item) for item in data) )
```

Prints:

```
4, Fred**, London**, 34, 78, @#=£**, 89, Ice cream**, Hamilton**, 12, tingle**
```